# Does SslStream.Dispose dispose its inner stream

Tags: c#, stream, dispose, sslstream

I use `NetworkStream` with sockets in an `SslStream` socket server as follows:

```
stream = new NetworkStream(socket, true); 
sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false);
```

My question is, if when I call `sslStream.Dispose()`, will the `SslStream` dispose/close its inner stream and its socket too?

Or do I need to explicitly close all three resources with `sslStream.Close()`, `stream.Close()` and `socket.Close()`?

Answer (score 4):

If possible, you should use C#'s `using` construct to dispose the stream 'automatically' after use:

```
using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false))
{
    // read from stream here...
}
```

However, if you want to keep the SslStream for later use, you will have to dispose manually.

Disposing a stream typically closes the stream as well, the `Close()` method seems to be there mostly for completeness. You can download the .NET source code (or use a decompiler), and examine the `SslStream.cs` and its base class `AuthenticatedStream.cs` to see the exact behaviour.

To answer the rest of your question - The [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d50tfa1c) is well documented on Microsoft's [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401) site which shows [one of `SslStream`'s constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6edd48se.aspx) takes two parameters (also shown by your example). The first parameter is the inner stream - which in your example the `NetworkStream` object. The second is a boolean called `leaveInnerStreamOpen`. In your example, you pass `false`.

It is this second value that determines the behaviour you are asking about: If you pass `true`, *the inner stream will remain open* when you close/dipose the SslStream (the stream will also be flushed). If you pass `false`, then *the inner stream will be closed too*.

Similarly for the `NetworkStream`, its constructor also takes a boolean `ownsSocket`. If this is set to `true` (as in your example), then disposing/closing the NetworkStream *will also close its socket*, otherwise it stays open.

Therefore, as your example code stands, you must call both `sslStream.Dispose()` *and* `stream.Dispose()` (the socket is closed automatically).

However, if you change the second parameter in the `SslStream`'s constructor to `true` in your example code, you can just call `sslStream.Dispose()` to close the `SslStream`, the `NetworkStream`, and its socket.

Comment: ssl constructor true means leave inner stream open, that mean eventhough sslstream is closed , inner stream remains open.I think sslstream construnctor should have false inorder to close inner stream.

Thanks

Comment: What is the default value of leaveInnerStreamOpen?

Comment: @daisy There is no 'default' really, as the caller must decide what to pass to the constructor (depending on how the underlying stream is being used). If you just want to use `SslStream` and don't care about the 'leave inner stream open' behavior, then use the other constructor without this parameter, like: `new SslStream(stream)`. The framework will then call the other constructor with a 'default' value of `leaveInnerStreamOpen`=`false`. This is like handing over the inner stream you created to the SslStream object and saying "you are in charge of this stream now, not me".